# Python query for Oracle

Tags: python, oracle

I'm running a query with the following fragment:

`... WHERE SOME_RECORD_ID = :1 AND SOME_USER_ID = :2`  .... and so on

The issue is that `:2` can be a Python None (Oracle NULL) and the condition

`SOME_USER_ID = NULL` will be false, even if SOME_USER_ID is indeed NULL in the ORACLE table.

I am looking to change the query so that if `:2` in None (or Null), then the query should behave as

```
WHERE SOME_RECORD_ID = :1 AND SOME_USER_ID **IS** :2
```

otherwise

```
WHERE SOME_RECORD_ID = :1 AND SOME_USER_ID **=** :2
```

I would appreciate any suggestion on a query rework

Comment: What is a qry? I am not familiar with the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
SOME_USER_ID = :2
```

to

```
NVL(SOME_USER_ID, '***NULL SENTINEL VALUE***') = NVL(:2, '***NULL SENTINEL VALUE***')
```

or something similar.

To ensure reasonable performance you may need to add a function-based index on `NVL(SOME_USER_ID, '***NULL SENTINEL VALUE***')`

Comment: The Oracle way is to use `decode`, which treats two `null` as the same. `... where decode(some_user_id, :2, 0) = 0`.